# Ionic 3 Tab pages lifecycle methods to update each tab page

Tags: ionic3

I have 3 tabs in my ionic 3 project.
first time, when I run the project each tab click event loads all the data from server, as I am calling the get data method in constructor.
When I toggle between the tabs, the method in the constructor doe not get called.
I need to update the data after each tab is clicked / toggled.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's a wonderful question.

You can use Lifecycle of ionic like `ionViewWillEnter` to call `api` every time you click on tab.

That's it. Easy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What if you put it in a function, call it once in the constructor and call it on every tab click ?